# Entity Framework does not seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, seed

I am currently learning Entity Framework. To learn it better, I decided to create a car rental application, taking some ideas from expedia, etc.

At this point my program works, I can add, edit, delete from database, although my seed does not work.

I am open to any suggestions for improvement of this code, and how to fix issue I am experiencing.

Thanks

Link to repo: https://github.com/tharion85/Car-Rental

Done following this guide: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

Your `CarInitializer` class inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` this means it will drop, create and run seed only if the model has changed. You can try it by for example adding another property to your `Customer` model. If you do this the database will be recreated and seed will be executed. 
If you want to always recreate the database inherit your class from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` so change this:

```
public class CarInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CarContext>
```

to this:

```
public class CarInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CarContext>
```

Also notice that your current seed won't run properly because `Customer` depends on `Car` so you first need to create a car and then add its reference to the customer. Also you forgot about `rentStart` and `rentEnd` properties. So for example, your seed can look like this:

```
protected override void Seed(CarContext context)
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>
        {
            new Car { Id=1033, Model="Corolla", Mark="Toyota", hasAC=true, rentalCost=65 }

        };
        cars.ForEach(ca => context.Cars.Add(ca));

        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {Car = cars.First(), FirstName="Carson", LastName="Alexander", Address="183 Court Road", ZipCode="T7D 0C1", City="Toronto", rentStart = DateTime.Now, rentEnd = DateTime.Now },
            new Customer {Car = cars.First(), FirstName="Meredith", LastName="Alonso", Address="101 Baseline Rd", ZipCode="V4D 0G2", City="Vancouver", rentStart = DateTime.Now, rentEnd = DateTime.Now },
            new Customer {Car = cars.First(), FirstName="Arturo", LastName="Brand", Address="1043 34st", ZipCode="T5Z 3P1", City="Calgary", rentStart = DateTime.Now, rentEnd = DateTime.Now }
        };

        customers.ForEach(c => context.Customers.Add(c));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I already updated customers with rentStart and rentEnd. Right now, i am experiencing error with The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Customers_dbo.Cars_Id". The conflict occurred in database "carRental1", table "dbo.Cars", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated. Error at line 31:             context.SaveChanges();

Comment: I already told you. Add the car reference to the costumer. So for example `new Customer {Car = cars.First() ... }`